# Carousel Tela inteira Bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando fazer uma primeira tela de um site apenas com um Carousel, para que fique ocupando toda a tela do usuário (de forma responsiva). Entende? Tipo a tela index sempre será um carousel tela cheia. Tentei muita coisa da net, mas ainda não consegui. Nem mesmo usando como background-image, como já usei em páginas estáticas.

É como se a tela ficasse no tamanho da imagem. Mas queria que elas ficassem dentro da div e recebesse o tamanho da div principal, que por sua vez seria responsiva e ocuparia toda a tela do usuário.
Ajuda ae :D

```js
/* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}

/* Muda o tempo do carousel, e tira o mousehover */
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 3200,
  cycle: true,
  pause: "null"
})
```

```css
/* ------------ carousel -------------------*/

.carousel-inner {
  list-style: none;
  /* aqui tiro a opção de passar SLIDEs < >  */
  position: relative!important;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* apagar os tracinhos que indicam onde a posição do carousel */

.carousel-indicators {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  carousel  -->
<div class="col-md-12" id="slides">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="meuCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHbD.png" alt="primeiro slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHbD.png" alt="segundo slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHbD.png" alt="terceiro slide">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é aplicar a classe `w-100` à `div #meuCarousel`, aplicar o seguinte CSS à classe `.carousel-item`:

```
.carousel-item{
   height: 100vh; /* dimensiona o slider à altura do viewport */
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

E usar o jQuery abaixo para converter as imagens em `background`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".carousel-item").each(function() {
      var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
      $(this)
      .css("background-image","url("+src+")")
      .find("img")
      .remove();
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".carousel-item").each(function() {
      var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
      $(this)
      .css("background-image","url("+src+")")
      .find("img")
      .remove();
   });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner{ 
 list-style: none; /* aqui tiro a opção de passar SLIDEs < >  */
 position: relative!important;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* apagar os tracinhos que indicam onde a posição do carousel */
.carousel-indicators{
 opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-item{
   height: 100vh;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-12" id="slides">
  <div class="row">

   <div id="meuCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#meuCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="primeiro slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/hrc-tigre-siberiano-2-jpg_21253111.jpg" alt="segundo slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://www.salford.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0008/890072/varieties/lightbox.jpg" alt="terceiro slide">
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Fala Phelipe. 
Brother, obg desde já, mas essa config acho que já resolvi com a classe w-100.
Porém é justamente esse scroll que não quero. Quero a imagem se adequando as telas. 
No width ela fica ok, quando diminuo a tela ela fica ok no width, mas se eu deixar, por exemplo, no formato mobile, ela mostra uma parte branca em baixo, não completando o heigth... penso ser isso...

Queria deixar assim -> http://sdrnaweb.com/   <- redimensiona esta página pra você sacar como estou falando...

Comment: Entendi, mas dependendo da proporção da tela, a imagem é cortada.

Comment: @EvertonLevi Atualizei a resposta com uma sugestão bem prática.

Comment: Amigo, perfeito! O resultado é exatamente isso! Muito obrigado MESMO! 
Abraço!!!